# Fragment renders with enormous delay after onResume

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on a complex fragment displaying some time/schedule elements in rows/columns. Every element is created and added to `RelativeLayout` programatically after `HTTP request` with proper positioning using LayoutParams. Whole operation (pulling data, parsing, invlating views and adding them to layout) takes 1-2 seconds, but... after `Fragment's` `onResume()` callback there is enormous 5-10 seconds delay before anything appears on the screen.

Often there is 50-100 `Views` to be placed in the Layout.

Is there any way to investigate what is slowing rendering down? What time consuming operation could possibly be executed after onResume()? When does rendering happen?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

I just found out that for ~50 Views in my RelativeLayout there is over 2100 onMeasure calls. I was used to 3-5 onMeasure calls per View, not 100. I suppose this could be the reason, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you doing the HTTP request and the view processing in a background/worker thread or on the main thread? We're going to need some source code here.

Comment: I handle HTTP request using Retrofit. System won't allow to perform request in main thread.

Comment: if you do multiple `LayoutInflater.inflate()` and `findViewById()` calls on the main thread, it will be very expensive.

Comment: @tolgap findViewById is not expensive at all

Comment: @tolgap I just found out that for ~50 Views in my RelativeLayout there is over 2100 onMeasure calls. I was used to 3-5 onMeasure calls per View, not 100. I suppose this could be the reason, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @pskink well... it *used* to be expensive. One of the best practices were `ViewHolder`s in your `Adapter`s to stop calling `findViewById()` too often. I wouldn't be surprised if it has been *significantly* improved with new hardware and software.

Comment: @tolgap ViewHolders is a myth,  they really dont improve the performance that much,  see findViewById implementation and compare it other ViewGroup methods

Comment: You should be using an adapterview to only render what's needed any any one time instead of rendering everything at once.